# Cannot save form data in IE8

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8

Running Windows XP SP3

AUTOCOMPLETE checkboxes are indeed selected under CONTENT TAB and
ADVNCED TAB in options.

Autocomplete web addresses works.

Tried so far.
Removed IE8 reinstalled.
Cleared TEMP internet files
Rebooted after changes
Cleared save autocomplete options cleared password and form data, rebooted.
Turned autocomplete on for all 3 fields.
Reinstalled IE8 many times.
Removed IE8.
Reinstalled IE8.
It just won't save any form field in an web page I visit.

I even added a new user added to ADMIN group and that person has same issue
also. So not applicable to my admin username.

ProtectedStorage server is running.

System File Check did not find anything.

--

In the registry in
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Intelliforms
there should be 3 subkeys

SPW
Storage1
Storage2

On a PC that does work IE8 XP SP3, these subkeys are quite full of data.
On the PC that does not work, these Subkeys were missing.

I manually added the three subkeys, rebooted and still did not work.

Google search is not helping on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres the fix
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942090